# how use parameters in the path-string

Tags: symfony, twig

I am using Symfony2 and TWIG. With "path" I will open a second page and set some parameters.

```
{% set place = "The City" %}
<tr>
    <td class="tdstellenangebot_zelle">
        <a href="#" onclick="anzeige_job('{{ path("_anzeige_job",{kznr:102,ort:"unseren Standort in " {{ place }} ,filiale:1} ) }}')">
            The jobdescription
        </a>
    </td>
    <td class="tdstellenangebot_zelle textBold">{{ place }} </td>
</tr>
```

But the script dont work.

How can I set the place in the path with the variable ?

Thanks alot for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need simple concatenation:

```
{% set place = "The City" %}
<tr>
    <td class="tdstellenangebot_zelle">
        <a href="#" onclick="anzeige_job('{{ path("_anzeige_job", { kznr: 102, ort:"unseren Standort in " ~ place, filiale: 1 }) }}')">
            The jobdescription
        </a>
    </td>
    <td class="tdstellenangebot_zelle textBold">{{ place }} </td>
</tr>
```

Take a look at tilde sign `~`. It is like `+` in JavaScript and `.` in PHP and is used to concatenate strings.